# random number generator with interactive variable

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, generator

```js
const inputMin = document.getElementById('min');  
const inputMax = document.getElementById('max');
const done = document.getElementById('value');
const rGen = document.getElementById('rGen');

let min = 1;
let max = 100;

inputMin.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
function updateValue(ef) {
    min = + ef.target.value ;      
}
inputMax.addEventListener('input', updateValue1);

function updateValue1(e) {
    max = + e.target.value;

}
    function randomNumber(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

}

rGen.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    done["innerText"] = randomNumber(min, max);

    e.preventDefault()


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>generator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
    <body>

 <form id="rGen" class="form">
    <h1>Click generate </bold></h1>
    <label
            for="min">od
    </label>
    <input type="number" id="min" placeholder='1'>
    <label for="max">do</label>
    <input type="number" id="max" placeholder="100"  size="10"> <br>
    <button class="butt">GENERATE</button>
    <div id="value">
        7
    </div>
 </form>
</body>
   </html>
```

Could someone help me with this its little messy code , but i want to switch theese two  if **Min**   > **Max** because when is min > than max the code still works and its giving wrong numbers , or any advices how to make it cleaner . Thanks a lot

Comment: your code is working whats your problem

Comment: type in 51 as min and 50 as max and you'll see

Comment: Absolutely! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `randomNumber`, add check if min is greater than max. If so, switch them.

```js
const inputMin = document.getElementById('min');
const inputMax = document.getElementById('max');
const done = document.getElementById('value');
const rGen = document.getElementById('rGen');

let min = 1;
let max = 100;

inputMin.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(ef) {
  min = +ef.target.value;
}
inputMax.addEventListener('input', updateValue1);

function updateValue1(e) {
  max = +e.target.value;
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

rGen.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  if (min > max) {
    var temp = min;
    min = max;
    max = temp;
  }

  done["innerText"] = randomNumber(min, max);

  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="rGen" class="form">
      <h1>Click generate </bold>
      </h1>
      <label for="min">od
      </label>
      <input type="number" id="min" placeholder='1'>
      <label for="max">do</label>
      <input type="number" id="max" placeholder="100" size="10"> <br>
      <button class="butt">GENERATE</button>
      <div id="value">
        7
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or just use [randojs.com](https://randojs.com). It handles cases where max > max automatically.

```js
let min = 1;
let max = 100;

document.getElementById('min').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  min = Number(e.target.value);
});

document.getElementById('max').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  max = Number(e.target.value);
});

document.getElementById('rGen').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('value')["innerText"] = rando(min, max);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>generator</title>
    <script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="rGen" class="form">
      <h1>Click generate </bold>
      </h1>
      <label for="min">od
      </label>
      <input type="number" id="min" placeholder='1'>
      <label for="max">do</label>
      <input type="number" id="max" placeholder="100" size="10"> <br>
      <button class="butt">GENERATE</button>
      <div id="value">
        7
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you choose to use [randojs](https://randojs.com), make sure you have this script tag in the head of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks aaron , i finaly made it work as i wanted , Now when i put into min higher number than max , it automaticly switch them and give you nice result , thanks :)

```js
const inputMin = document.getElementById('min');
const inputMax = document.getElementById('max');
const done = document.getElementById('value');
const rGen = document.getElementById('click');



let min = 1;
let max = 10;

     inputMin.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
        function updateValue(e) {
         
            min = +e.target.value;
    }
    inputMax.addEventListener('input', updateValue1);
      function updateValue1(e) {
          
            max = +e.target.value;
    }
    
function randomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

rGen.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (min > max) {
        [min, max] = [max, min];

        inputMax.value = max;
        inputMin.value = min;
    
        done.innerText = randomNumber(min, max);
    }
    else {
        done.innerText = randomNumber(min, max);
    }
    
        e.preventDefault()
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>generator</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="texts.css">

</head>
<body>
        <div>
    <div class="Rgen-num" id="value">

    </div>

    <div class="Rgen-pick">
     <div class="upper-text">
      min
     </div>
     
      <input id="min" value="1" min="-99999999999999" max="99999999999999" type="number">

     </div>
     <div class="upper-text">
      max
     </div>
     
      <input id="max" value="10" min="-99999999999999" max="99999999999999" type="number">
     
    
   </div>
   <div class="bot-Rgen" id="click">
    <div class="bot-Rgen-text" style="cursor:pointer;color:red;">
    Click me to GENERATE
    </div>
        </div>

<script src="js/script1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it